# Modifying a computer object's whenCreated attribute within Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

I would like to modify the "whenCreated" attribute on a computer object using [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) from SysInternals. However, when I attempt to do it, I get the following error message in a dialog box:

```
Unable to update attribute:

The directory datatype cannot be converted to/from a native DS datatype
```

I am the owner of this computer object and have access to modify it. Is this not an attribute that can be updated on a Computer object?

Or are there any other ways to modify the creation date of this object? In essence, I'm looking for a "[touch](http://ss64.com/bash/touch.html)" utility for Active Directory objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *whenCreated* attribute may not be modified except by the system.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680924%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the associated documentation for that attribute.  Notice the "*Update Privilege: This value is set by the system.*" and "*System-Only: True*" parts of the document.  The [whenChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680921%28VS.85%29.aspx), [createTimeStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675468%28VS.85%29.aspx), and [modifyTimeStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677125%28VS.85%29.aspx) attributes all follow the same pattern.

As far as I know, there's nothing you are going to be able to do to modify *whenCreated* or *createTimeStamp* short of deleting the object and actually re-creating it.

If you're looking for a way to query recently changed AD objects, you should be querying *whenChanged* or *modifyTimeStamp*.  I'd suggest *whenChanged* because it's replicated in the global catalog.

To create a "touch* utility for AD objects, you'll need to find a non-important (to you) editable attribute that *whenChanged* is linked to.  You can then tweak that attribute and it should subsequently update the *whenChanged* value.  An example attribute might be *description*.  If you really want to get complex and not mess with any built-in attributes, you could alter your AD schema to add your own attribute.